# Use a Type Defined in Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

Apologies for the title - I really can't think of a very good way to describe my requirement.

I want to be able to define a generic interface (or class, it doesn't matter) whereby the Type parameter supplies another Type which can be accessed from the class. Hopefully this code snippet will explain.

```
interface IFoo
{
   TOtherType DependentType { get; }
}

interface IMyGeneric<TBar> where TBar : IFoo
{
   TBar ReturnSomeTBar();
   TBar.DependentType ReturnSomeTypeOnTBar();
}
```

So in this example I want a class to realise `IFoo` (e.g. `Foo`) and expose another type, DependentType (e.g. `int`) so I can use `IMyGeneric<Foo>` that has methods:

```
public Foo ReturnSomeTBar()
{
}

public int ReturnSomeTypeOnTBar()
{
}
```

Clearly the above code doesn't compile so is there a way to achieve this behaviour of generic chaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, IFoo would need to be generic too

```
interface IFoo<TDependent>
{
   TDependent DependentType { get; }
}
```

Then IMyGeneric would need to have 2 type params

```
interface IMyGeneric<TBar,TDependent> where TBar : IFoo<TDependent>
{
   TBar ReturnSomeTBar();
   TDependent ReturnSomeTypeOnTBar();
}
```

Perhaps this gets you closer to the solutin you;re after.

Answer (score 1):

`TBar.DependentType` would have to be a part of `TBar`, that's not the kind of this you can do a constraint on for a generic type parameter.

How about using 2 type parameters instead?  `IMyGenertic<TBar, TFoo>`?  Usable workaround?

Comment: Indeed the 2 type parameters was a workaround I'd considered, but it's not quite the behaviour I need as the types will be independent. It'll be an acceptable compromise though